# VSCODE Python Virtual Environment Not Showing Up

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

When I create the Virtual environment, it doesn't show up in the Explorer

[image]

Here's the example I followed from a Youtube video:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKq3C.png)

There is no bin folder and this command to activate didn't work.  Picture added
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKq3C.png)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Then type **Select Interpreter**

OR

Inside your `.vscode` folder, you will find a `settings.json` file.
It should contain, at minimum, the following setting:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "env\\Scripts\\python.exe"
}
```

Comment: There's nothing in this folder  C:\Users\TonyD\Documents\VSCODE

Comment: The correct folder is: your_project_folder\.vscode\settings.json

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't access to python.

Try run `python3` is this command open the python interpreter ?

Maybe try `py -m venv venv`

Do you try to run `source venv/bin/activate` ?